# How to specify different properties in a @wired method's object argument

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using [getRecordCreateDefaults](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_create_record_values) and it has an optional `recordTypeId` property in its argument object, defined as:

> (Optional)The ID of the record type (RecordType object) for the new
>   record. If not provided, the default record type is used.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecordCreateDefaults } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';

export default class DynamicForm extends LightningElement

    @api selectedRecordTypeId = null;

    @wire(getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$selectedRecordTypeId' })
    accountCreateDefaults;

    connectedCallback() {
        const data = this.accountCreateDefaults.data;
        // process it
    }
}
```

Sometimes `selectedRecordTypeId` will be supplied and other times it will not, and will be null. If `selectedRecordTypeId` is null the `getRecordCreateDefaults` returns an empty object. That is, `this.accountCreateDefaults` is an empty object. If `selectedRecordTypeId` is a valid record type ID, it all works fine.

The `recordTypeId` property is optional in the object argument, so if I don't include it at all then it also works, returning the desired, default data.

However, there does not seem to be a way to sometimes specify `recordTypeId` as a property in the wired object parameter, and sometimes not.

I thought I found a workaround by calling the method imperatively, but that is forbidden by the framework and results in a run-time error of "Imperative use is not supported". Of course, I could just use Apex, but that defeats the benefit of the built in wired service.

**How to specify different properties in a @wired method's object argument?**

Comment: To clarify this, so you are looking to *dynamically* invoke the wired services based on the input, e.g., `getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$selectedRecordTypeId' }` when you have `selectedRecordTypeId` and `getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT}` when you don't have one, is that correct?

Comment: @JayantDas - Yes

Comment: Seems the platform cannot really handle a `null` value passed in that parameter. [@tsalb's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/260153/54851) seems to be a good workaround for this *limitation*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first tried the following, but the linter complained: `LWC1094: @wire expects a configuration object expression as second parameter.`

```js
_config = {}; // was trying to set this as the object

@wire(getRecordCreateDefaults, '$_config')
  accountCreateDefaults;
```

Which told me that it's not possible to bypass feeding in an object in its entirety. So then...it seems you might need two wires - one for each version (with and without recordTypeId) and defer runtime until you've calculated it like this:

```js
@wire(getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
wiredAccountDefaults;

@wire(getRecordCreateDefaults, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$selectedRecordTypeId' })
wiredAccountDefaultsWithRecordType;

connectedCallback() {
  const data = this.wiredAccountDefaultsWithRecordType // prefer recordTypeId version.
    ? this.wiredAccountDefaultsWithRecordType.data
    : this.wiredAccountDefaults.data;
  // process it
}
```

I too would like to know if there is a cleaner way, because this seems like an oversight to include optional parameters in @wire modules but not having a clean way to dynamically omit them.

Comment: +1. I agree with your point that it shouldn't have been really that difficult to ignore the parameter if there was no value passed. But your approach does provide a workaround.

Comment: I added this idea: [Provide a way to specify different properties to @wired method's object argument](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003dABQAY).